# I want to search particular files from directory in perl

Tags: grep, perl

Need file pattern search(in perl), something like `$fileName =~ / /`. Specif filename examples:

```
YYYY-MM-DD_AmdocsWebHourlyReport.csv.gz

YYYY-MM-DD_ComverseHourlyReport.csv.gz

YYYY-MM-DD_DailyShortCodeSummaryReport.csv.gz

YYYY-MM-DD_SS7Statistic sReport.csv.gz
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? Is it your intent to search for files on your hard-drive using a text file as the input source for the search?

Comment: You want to only find files with specific filename or you want to find files AND do something with them ? Please clarify

Comment: just need find specific files

Comment: You can use wildcards with the `name` or `iname` tests of `find`, and then for example move them somewhere else: `find /in/some/directory -iname '*Report.csv.gz' -exec mv {} /some/where/else \;`

Comment: Does it have to be perl specifically ? ( it can very well be done, just curious if you are open to simpler solutions )

Comment: yeah ..i m writing perl script

Comment: Answer posted. Please check

Comment: there could be more files like 2017-03-01_tmobileWebHourlyReport.csv.gz or maybe 2017-03-01_bmwReport.csv.gz which should not be part of the result bcoz these file name are diffrent from AmdocsWebHourlyReport, ComverseHourlyReport, DailyShortCodeSummaryReport, SS7Statistic

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the `File::Find` module. The `find()` function from the module traverses given directory tree and executes a specific subroutine defined within that function (although that could well be defined outside).

Below is an example of usage. Here we find all the files and push them into array, so that you can later iterate over each array item and do something with it; it's necesssary since `find()` doesn't like it when you attempt to alter a file *during* traversal of the directory tree. Adapt the script as necessary

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my @wanted_files;
# The wanted subroutine is enclosed into find(sub,dir) command
# but can be used outside as well  
find(
     sub{ 
         -f $_ && $_ =~ /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*csv.gz/  
               && push @wanted_files,$File::Find::name
     }, "."
);

foreach(@wanted_files){
    print "$_\n"
}
```

Test run:

```
$ tree
.
├── 2017-03-01_AmdocsWebHourlyReport.csv.gz
├── 2017-03-01_ComverseHourlyReport.csv.gz
├── 2017-03-02_AmdocsWebHourlyReport.csv.gz
├── 2017-03-02_ComverseHourlyReport.csv.gz
├── find_files.pl
└── some_random_file.blah

0 directories, 6 files
$ ./find_files.pl                                                                                                        
./2017-03-02_ComverseHourlyReport.csv.gz
./2017-03-01_ComverseHourlyReport.csv.gz
./2017-03-02_AmdocsWebHourlyReport.csv.gz
./2017-03-01_AmdocsWebHourlyReport.csv.gz
```